# How to get the default image of the SharePoint header banner image?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api, modern-experience, image, sitepages

Does anyone know if it is possible to get the SharePoint header banner image?

By downloading it or a way to get it from the SharePoint page.

[image]

Comment: Do you want download it manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the Banner Image URL of particular site page using SharePoint REST API endpoint like:

```
https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/wlive/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Site%20Pages')/items(3)?$select=Title,BannerImageUrl
```

Then you can open the image URL from response in new tab, right click on image and use **Save image as...** option to download it.

---

OR if you want to do it from browser, follow below steps:

1. Go to Site pages library
2. Click on **+Add column** option and select **Show or hide columns** option:

   [image]
3. Select Banner Image URL column and click Apply:

   [image]
4. It will add image column in library view. You can inspect the `img` element using browser developer tools to get the image URL:

   [image]
5. Right click on image URL and select **Open in new tab** option
6. Right click on image and use **Save image as...** option to download it

This way you will be able to get the images for multiple pages in your site from one single location (from Site Pages library).

Comment: This solution doesnt tell with which page the image is mapped to as a banner.

Comment: You can see the page name (`Open-Door-Policy.aspx`) in my last screenshot which clearly tells you the page and it's corresponding banner image next to it in the screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

1. Right click on banner image and inspect it, you can see the source ( public CDN)
2. Copy image source url and paste in browser
3. Right click and select save image as